# Cloning vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector, clone

Hello I'm new here and new to C++. I have a problem where I need to make backup copy of my vector of pointers. But I can't relly get it properly. I found solution to my case on this forum but can't relly get it right:

```
class cloneFunctor {
public:
    T* operator() (T* a) {
        return a->clone();
    }
}
```

I tried to implement this into my code but could't get a good resolve, could anyone help me to get this thing right?

My code:

sever.cpp

```
  #include "server.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <functional>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iterator>
    class Client;


    class cloneFunctor {
    public:
        cloneFunctor* operator() (cloneFunctor* a) {
            return a->clone();
        }
    };

    Server *Server::instance = 0;

    Server& Server::getInstance() {
        if (instance == 0)
            instance = new Server();
        return (*instance);
    }

    void Server::setStatus(bool status) {
        this->nStatus = status;
        changeClientStatus();
        writeStateToConsole();
    }

    bool Server::getStatus() {
        return nStatus;
    }

    void Server::writeStateToConsole() {
        std::cout << "Server state: " << getStatus() << std::endl;
    }

    void Server::subscribeToServer(Client &temp) {
        listOfClients.push_back(&temp);
    }
    void Server::writeClients() {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < listOfClients.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << i+1  << ". client status: " << listOfClients[i]->getStatus() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void Server::changeClientStatus() {
        if (nStatus == 0){
            makeCopy(listOfClients);
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < listOfClients.size(); i++) {
                listOfClients[i]->setStatus(false);
            }
        }
        else
            restoreCopy();

    }

    void Server::makeCopy(std::vector<Client *>listOfClients) {
         transform(listOfClients.begin(), listOfClients.end(), back_inserter(listOfClientsOld), cloneFunctor());
    }
    void Server::restoreCopy() {


    }
```

server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H_
#define SERVER_H_

#include "abstractbaseclass.h"
#include "server.h"
#include "client.h"



class Client;
class Server : public Abstractbaseclass {
    friend class Client;
public:
    static Server& getInstance();
    virtual void setStatus(bool status);
    virtual bool getStatus();
    virtual void writeStateToConsole();
    void subscribeToServer(Client &temp);
    void writeClients();
    void changeClientStatus();
    void makeCopy(std::vector<Client *>listOfClients);
    void restoreCopy();


 private:
    static Server *instance;
    Server(){};
    std::vector <Client *>listOfClients;
    std:: vector <Client *> listOfClientsOld;
};


#endif /* SERVER_H_ */
```

Program should create singleton Server class, and then create 3 clients who will subsribe to server (these are hold in vector of pointers). When I set server status to 0, all clients change their state to off (bool false) and befeore this should be created backup vector, becouse when I'll turn on server again clients need to switch to their state from before shutting down server.

Comment: If the clients are not modified while the server isn't running you are doing a lot of extra work. Conceptually you may be better off not keeping copies of the vector, but making the `Clients` responsible for backing up and reverting themselves. This keeps the server really stupid and makes it harder for the server to arbitrarily screw with client's state by copying over it or supplanting it.

Comment: That's not actually my idea how to solve it, this is how our teacher wanted it, so I have to deal with it, and "make his wish come true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so he's trying to teach some sort of transaction-based thinking.

`Client` may need an assignment operator

```
Client & operator=(Client & toCopy)
{
    // copy all of toCopy's members over to this
}
```

if it doesn't already have one  and contains pointers or complex data types that you can't trust to self-copy.

Now you can easily

```
clientA = clientB;
```

to copy `clientB` into `clientA`

Then we get to the main event, `Server::restoreCopy()`, and it's a brutally simple variant of:

```
if (listOfClients.size() != listOfClientsOld.size())
{
    // back up is stale. Probably throw exception
}
for (size_t index = 0; index < listOfClients.size(); index++)
{
    *listOfClients[index] = *listOfClientsOld[index];
}
```

These are `vector`s of pointers so you must dereference (`*`) the pointer to get the pointed at `Client` or you copy the pointer and not the pointed at. Remember that clone of `Client` is a totally different `Client`and not what `Server`'s  user passed in in the first place. If the `Server` user is still holding onto the initial `Client` and using it, bad ju-ju will happen if you only copy the pointers. Both sides will be operating on different `Client`s even though they may look the same. So much as one modification and they won't

You can also use the `std::transform` trick used to make the back-up here as well, but this is simple and obvious and easy to debug. Feel free to use iterators and range-based `for` as well.

And while you are at it, pray no one has reordered `listOfClients` since you made the back-up.

Important side notes:

```
void makeCopy(std::vector<Client *>listOfClients);
```

is weird. It allows a `Server` user to pass in their own `vector` and add to any existing back-ups. This includes `Server` itself. It does not remove any existing back up, so `listOfClientsOld` will keep growing. And because anyone who has access to the `Server` can call it and pass in their own `vector`, they can stuff that back up full of fallacious nonsense. I'd recommend that `makeCopy` take no parameters and remove any existing `Clients` from the backup, and `delete` them. Better still, `listOfClientsOld` has no need to store pointers at all and probably shouldn't.

Lots of pointers in play and no `delete`s. Somebody has to give back all of that memory you're allocating or you'll eventually run out.